# Unexpected token < exception when I set charset="utf-8" in js file

Tags: javascript, jsp, utf-8

I have book.jsp and book.js file. I was trying to set charset in js file like below.

```
<script src="/js/view/page1/main/book/book.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"/>
```

Jsp content loading without issue but getting below exception in the console while trying to load js file for that page.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Comment: If I remove this from js file then the page loads without any issue `<script src="/js/view/page1/main/book/book.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"/>`

Comment: Blind guess: is your JS file is in UTF with BOM?

Comment: Yes, I am using...

Comment: I don't actually understand the "Yes, I am using..." message, but if it means that your file is in UTF with BOM, so the problem is clear: you're trying to open file with wrong encoding. Just save your files in UTF8 without BOM, or load 'em with UTF+BOM. By the way, show the full code of the page.

Comment: I was not using UTF for my js file. Now I am going to use UTF character set in my file.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure to close the tag.

```
<script src="/js/view/page1/main/book/book.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed this symbol (>)  in question.

Comment: I updated my answer with the completed code. Please try this and see if it works.

Comment: I have tried your solution but no luck, still getting the same exception.